# How to find the relative order between two functions $f(n)$ and $g(n)$?

Tags: limits, algorithms, asymptotics

I have two functions:
$$f(n) = n^{a-1}$$

$$g(n) = 2^{\sqrt{\ln(n)}}$$

I know that I can use the limit rule which involves calculating the limit $\dfrac{n^{a-1}}{2^{\sqrt{\ln(n)}}}$

Because it's not obvious where the limit is trending towards we have to use the L'Hôpital's rule. $f(n)$ complicates things because it doesn't give a simple derivative. Am I doing it wrong?

I thought I pretty much had to use the L'Hôpital's rule because considering that $\ln(n)$ is increasing we have $2^∞$. which seems to be indeterminate like $1^{∞}$. Maybe my assumption is wrong?

Comment: first of all you should use at least a comma between the two functions, the way you have written is confusing and there is nothing named "limit rule", there is some properties namely "limit properties", also "L'Hôpital's" rule is used when we have an indeterminate form not when we even don't know what the limit point does tend to, also it seems you have a sequence, not a **real valued function** so the derivative would be discontinuous, therefore you cannot use this rule.

Comment: If the square root sign were not there we could write $\ln n=\ln 2 \cdot \log_2 n, 2^{\ln n}=2^{\ln 2\cdot \log_2 n}=n^{\ln 2}$ and compare easily with $f(n)$ with the result depending on $a$.  What have you  tried?  This looks like a fairly high level problem to me because of the square root.

Comment: $\sqrt{\ln(n)}$ is $ln(x)$ such that $x^x=n$ no ?

Answer (score 1):

I claim that for large enough $n$, $f(n) \gt g(n)$ if $a \gt 1$, while $g(n) \gt f(n)$ if $a \le 1$

The second part is the easy one.  If $a \le 1, f(n) \le 1$ and $g(n) \to \infty$

For the first, we note that $\ln n=\ln 2 \cdot \log_2 n, 2^{\ln n}=2^{\ln 2\cdot \log_2 n}=n^{\ln 2}, 2^{\frac {\ln n}k}=n^{\frac{\ln 2}k}$

For any natural $k$, when $n \gt e^{k^2}, \ln n \gt k^2$.  When $n$ is that large $\sqrt{\ln n} \lt \frac {\ln n}k$.  In that case $g(n)=2^{\sqrt{\ln n}}\lt 2^{\frac{\ln n}k}=n^{\frac{\ln 2}k}$

Given $a \gt 1$, choose $k$ large enough that $\frac 1k \lt a-1$.  Then for $n \gt e^{k^2}\quad f(n) \gt g(n)$